# Syntax for echoing link in PHP

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

I'm trying to string together a URL and then get it to echo out a link

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.google.com/#q='.$word;
echo '<a href="'.$url.'" id="link">' 'Google This!' '</a>';  
?>
```

Pretty sure it is an issue with the quotes however I'm unsure of how to fix them? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<a href="'.$url.'" id="link"> Google This! </a>';
```

Comment: You can actually echo more than one string if you separate them with commas. `echo 'string', 'string', 'string';`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.google.com/#q='.urlencode($word);
echo '<a href="'.htmlentities($url).'" id="link">Google This!</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href="'.$url.'" id="link">' . 'Google This!' . '</a>';
```

OR

```
echo '<a href="'.$url.'" id="link">Google This!</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most otimized way to do that is :

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.google.com/#q='.$word;
echo '<a href="'.$url.'" id="link">Google This!</a>';
?>
```

You can have more informations about strings at : http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a break in your string without concatenating.

```
>' 'Google This!' '</
```

Should be:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.google.com/#q='.urlencode($word);
echo '<a href="'.$url.'" id="link">'.'Google This!'.'</a>';  
?>
```

Always safe to use "urlencode()" as well. [See php documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php). It makes sure all characters are safe in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

personally all those single and double quotes drive me crazy so whenever possible i make the php variable and then echo out just what is needed in the html

```
<?php  $url = 'https://www.google.com/#q='.urlencode($word); ?>

<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" id="link">Google This!</a>
```